# Remove space at the top of first row in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, ios7

In my application i'm using custom cell in table view to display images in all rows. But in my .xib file there is a big empty space comes at the top of the custom cell. Can anyone tell me that how remove that space in iOS7 (iPad)? (like how to change the Y axis of the custom cell)

Comment: Please post a screenshot of IB.

Comment: In your XIB Navigation bar are there?

Answer (score 2):

This is an IOS7 related issue with UITableViewStyleGrouped and size of footer views in section.

If you set the footerView to be size 0 it defaults to a larger value, The solution I found was to set the footer to a very small non zero number

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0.0000001f;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set into your property inspector like this..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        UILabel *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
        sectionHeader.hidden = YES;
        return sectionHeader;    
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 0;
}
```

Sometimes the empty space in the first row is the section header space. This functions eliminate it.